# Explanation of a natural transformation in group theoretic terms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory

In category theory, a functor looks like homomorphism between categories.  Keeping that analogy in mind, can a natural transformation be described by (or restricted to) group theoretic terms?  For example, can they be described by groups of homomorphisms?

Comment: Are you asking what a natural transformation of homomorphisms between groups (viewed as categories with one element) is?

Comment: In general, no.  I'm more comfortable with group theory than category theory, so I'm trying to understand the concept of natural transformations in group theory first before moving back to category theory.  Certainly, one way to do this is just to look at the category of groups, but I'm hoping there's a more direct analogy.

Comment: I don't mean looking at the category Grp, I mean looking at groups as a special case of categories.

Comment: I misunderstood then.  Yes, I think that would help answer my question.

Comment: E.g. if we have two group homomorphisms $f,g:X\to Y$ then a natural transformation between $f$ and $g$ is an element $\eta\in Y$ such that for any $x\in X, \eta f(x)=g(x)\eta$, i.e. $f(x)=\eta^{-1}g(x)\eta$. Thus two group homomorphisms are related by a natural translation iff they differ by an inner automorphism. Edit: posting this as an answer.

Comment: A natural transformation $F \to G$ between functors $F,G \colon \mathcal A \to \mathcal B$ is *the same as* a functor $H \colon\mathcal A \times \{0 \to 1\} \to \mathcal B$ such that $F = H(-,0)$ and $G = H(-,1)$. If you understand functors as some kind of "maps", you can understand natural transformations as some kind of "homotopies".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that a small category with only one object in which all morphisms are invertible is precisely a group, and functors between such categories are group homomorphisms. Thus we can understand natural transformations as a generalization of some notion of equivalence of group homomorphisms.

If we have two group homomorphisms $f,g:X\to Y$ then a natural transformation between $f$ and $g$ is an element $\eta\in Y$ such that for any $x\in X, \eta f(x)=g(x)\eta$, i.e. $f(x)=\eta^{-1}g(x)\eta$. Thus two group homomorphisms are related by a natural translation iff they differ by an inner automorphism.